# Ajuste com layout ReactNative

Tags: react-native

Quero fazer um layout da seguinte forma:

```
<ScrollView style={{flexDirection:'row'}]>
  <View style={{flex:1}}></View>
  <View style={{flex:1}}></View>
  <View style={{flex:1}}></View>
  <View style={{flex:1}}></View>
  <View style={{flex:1}}></View>
  <View style={{flex:1}}></View>
  <View style={{flex:1}}></View>
</ScrollView>
```

De forma que à cada 3 View, os outros venham pra baixo. Porém, o sistema imprime 7 colunas.

Como fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi usando `flexWrap:'wrap'` e porcentagens:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
  <View style={{ width: '33.333%' }}></View>
  <View style={{ width: '33.333%' }}></View>
  <View style={{ width: '33.333%' }}></View>
  <View style={{ width: '33.333%' }}></View>
  <View style={{ width: '33.333%' }}></View>
  <View style={{ width: '33.333%' }}></View>
  <View style={{ width: '33.333%' }}></View>
</View>
```